# JavaFX - Get textfield from multiples nodes

Tags: java, javafx, nodes, textfield

I need to do a validation and get the value from textfield inside of combobox, datepicker, timepicker...

I want to pass the ComboBox or DatePicker as Node to a method.
It will be called "srcControl".

```
ComboBox<?> comboField = (ComboBox<?>) srcControl.get();
DatePicker comboField = (DatePicker) srcControl.get();
```

From that control I want to get `textfield`, every `ComboBox` and `DatePicker` have a `textfield`.

How to get textfield from the node without explicity DatePicker or ComboBox class?

Comment: I don't truly understand what you need to do or what your question is.

Comment: @Sedrick, better?

Comment: You can't. `ComboBox` and `DatePicker` declare the `editor` property on their own. The common superclass `ComboBoxBase` does not contain this property. You inevitably need to use the types to access the property unless you want to use reflection which I don't recommend...

Comment: Surely you would validate the value you get from calling `getValue()` on these controls; you wouldn't try to validate by extracting the value from the text field. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @James_D Yes, Can I `getValue()` from them?

Comment: Of course. `getValue()` is defined in `ComboBoxBase`